# Save the background image of a rectangle using file dialog in javafx

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have two rectangles in my scene .Then I set a background in those rectangles using `setFill()` and make some changes.How do I save those images to disk using `saveDialog` ? Here is my save function -

```
  FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
  fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "*.png", "*.jpg", "*.gif"));
  fileChooser.setTitle("Save Image");
  File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(window);
  rect2.getFill();
  SaveFile(file);
```

Comment: What do you want to save? An actual image (that you could open in another program), or the data describing the background color?

Comment: the actual image after the changes are made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `javafx.scene.image.Image` from any node by calling [`snapshot(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) on the node:

```
Image img = rect2.snapshot(null, null);
```

The [`javax.imageio.ImageIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) class has methods for saving images in standard formats, but only works with AWT images, so you need to convert it first:

```
BufferedImage bImg = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(img, null);
String format = file.getName().substring(file.getName().lastIndexOf(".")+1);
ImageIO.write(bImg, format, file);
```